# wp_nav_menu() custom container and container_id

Tags: customization, theme-development, menus

So today I started work on my first Wordpress theme and so far it's been a  lot of fun. However, I have had difficulty in getting wp_nav_menu() to do what I want.

Here's what I want:

```
<nav id="topnav" class="menu">
   <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Looking in the documentation, I would expect the following call to do what I want:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'container' => 'nav', 'container_id' => 'topnav' )); ?>
```

But instead I get this:

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

To me it looks like my custom parameters are being ignored as the output from `wp_nav_menu()` is exactly the same. Is there something I need to turn on somewhere to enable this or is there something else going on?

**EDIT**

Curiously, if I change `menu_class` it alters the div's class (I expected the div to be the container) but changing `menu_id` does nothing.

**EDIT 2**

Even going into nav-menu-template.php and changing the defaults for container, container_id, container_class, menu_id does nothing. Changing menu_class to yyy will change the div's class from menu to yyy.

Comment: vote some of the answers so others can see which is more fitting for you. add some comments so it's easier to help.

Comment: I believe the menu_id [ok I was mistaken: got confused between menu_id and menu... ;menu_id' should work as you expect it; the rest applies to 'menu'] argument is to let you specify the id of the menu you'd like displayed. Usually this is left blank so that the default behavior takes place: look for what menu is tied to the menu location specified by the theme_location argument

Answer (score 6):

i had the save problem: it's because if you don't create the menu in the admin wordpress use a fallback method and creates the menu out of all active pages ... and if this happens than the options from wp_nav_menu are not used ...

so: just create the menu in the admin and u can change the wrapper-tag to "nav"

Comment: +1 if no menus are available then fallback is used and arguments are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you won't be able to get WordPress to output any kind of `<nav>` element using native functions.  `<nav>` is an HTML5 tag, and WordPress is built to generate XHTML output ... i.e. no `<nav>` element.

---

***Edit:** Apparently the function does allow `nav` ... but keep in mind that the rest of the WordPress core is still built to output XHTML, not HTML5 ... take care to make sure your site validates properly.*

---

Try removing that reference ... it might be causing the error that's ignoring your `'container_id' => 'topnav'` instruction.  If things work right without the reference to `nav` you should have this:

```
<div id="topnav" class="menu">
   <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `wp_nav_menu(array('container_id' => 'topnav' ));` still won't work right.

Looking at this post (not the Codex) http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus where it explains the parameters: "container: The element that wraps around the list. The default is div but can be changed to nav if you’ve moved on to HTML 5."

Comment: What plug-ins are you using on the site?  All of the arguments for `wp_nav_menu` are passed through the filter `wp_nav_menu_args` ... could there be some code on your site (in the theme or a plug-in) that's overriding your settings?

Comment: This is a fresh install of Wordpress 3.0.1. No plugins or strange confuguration.  The only thing I've changed is the theme.

Comment: Curiously, if I change menu_class it alters the div's class (I expected the div to be the container) but changing menu_id does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The Menu API is partially broken, you can not rely on the output. There are diverse tickets in trac regarding that, I only did a quick search, but maybe a solution for your problem is explained in one of them:

- [#14560 - class 'current-page-parent' is being to the parent page and to the parent page of other menu items](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14560)
- [#14529 - wp_nav_menu() gives different results when called multiple times - reproducable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14529)
- [#14208 - by adding a custom menu with the url without the slash (/) the menu dont active in front page](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14208)
- [#14250 - wp_nav_menu separator and first last class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14250)

Comment: Ah ok. For the time being I'll just output the menu to a string and use good old str_replace to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if anyone is still looking to solve this - but just got here trying to find the answer myself - thought I'd share my solution :)

Also wanted to use the <nav> instead of the <div> element and solved it by removing the <div>, as stated on this page, [wordpress codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu):

```
<?php
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' )
{
    $args['container'] = false;
    return $args;
} // function

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
?>
```

Added to my functions.php file, marked up the theme file with the <nav> tag & all worked fine for me ;) hope this helps :)